# How can i send values from android edit text to my web site for login?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I have a web site and this web site starts a login panel.I want to make android app for my web site.How can i send login values from android edittext from web site?I can try http post but i couldn't made it

Comment: You need to write a Web Service. Or as a WebView you can open the site within the application. But not healthy. To use the database on the website within the application, you must type api.  https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Hi, Can you please share code? so we can fix exact problem which you are facing.Thanks

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You didn't provided enough information to developers.

Comment: @HasanKucuk Ok.I will try.Thanks your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a web site for business. Our customer login this web site and see their accounting. Now, we want an Android app for this. You can think like facebook and facebook mobile app. Customer will enter own user name, password and achieve company accounting on web site but not redirect to web login page. So when information is entered from the application, you can log in without having to re-enter information on the login page of the web page.

Comment: You should edit your question, not post a answer to your own question.

Comment: Consider using a `WebView` if you want an app that embeds a website. Also consider using long lived cookies.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here.I didn't saw edit button.Next time I'll be careful